# How to debug Android Emulator?

Tags: android, debugging, emulation

I want to debug Android emulator source code in order to get deeper understanding of the simulator. It would be great if I can debug with Eclipse.

I have found just a little information about Android emulator source code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-13.htm). This will guide you how to debug in step by step.

To get Different **shout-Cuts** >> click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Thank you but I want to debug Android emulator source code, not Java program.

Comment: what mean that ? sorry i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what platform you're on, but basically compile it with all debugging symbols, if in linux you can open with gdb or cgdb also providing the source tree and you'll be able to see everything in the context of the source code.

I haven't used eclipse for this purpose but http://wiki.eclipse.org/DSDP/DD/GDB looks promising ...

I'm sure someone can tell you how to do this with windows if you can't figure it out with uncle google.